# Help with determining the right statistical test to find the best performing social post

Tags: r, python

The following table shows Reach, Engagement and Engagement Rate (Engagement/Reach) for 10 posts posted on Facebook in a span of 1 week.

[image: Social Media Posts]

Now, just by seeing the table, if I want to determine the top performing post in terms of Engagement Rate, then Post3 seems to be the winner. However, if I look closely, then Post3 has reached only 10 people and out of them 4 of them engaged with the post. Hence, this posts's Engagement Rate is high (40%). On the contrary, if I see Post4, even though it has lesser Engagement Rate (3%) than Post3, it reached higher number of people and higher engagement than Post3. I think the Reach and Engagement for Post3 is not significant enough to conclude it is the best performing post. I want to prove this statistically by running some test like t-test, chi-square test etc. (new to stats).

I am trying to think in terms of methods used in this article: https://www.optimizesmart.com/conversion-rate-statistically-significant/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Judging by engagement rates, 3 is the best. If you don't think so, you need to state why, so we can help you understand what assumptions you are making and what statistical tools are appropriate.

Comment: i would second. perhaps the question is wrongly put.

Comment: @Arpit Thank you for your quick response. What I intend to do is find the best performing post statistically. If I go with the post with the highest Engagement Rate then I would have Post 3 as the best performing one (40%). However if I see it's Reach and Engagement figures, then they are merely 10 and 4 resp. which, I think is not right. Maybe it is not a right representation of the data. I want to run some kind of a statistical test (like z-test, chi-square test etc.) which can help me determine the best performing post. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: @avinax, i think you need to have more business understanding of problem. Please ask what defines best? As far i know in your case best should be defined in monetary terms like income from every view/engagement than only you can define best.Then you can even think of applying any test. Also ur problem is deterministic , you don't need any test for this.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "BEST" defined by engagement rate only? If so, maximum value will give you best post. Isn't it?